# DISTINCT not working for how can i fix this

Tags: java, hibernate

```
 try {
        Session s = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Product.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("Gender", "Men"));
        c.setResultTransformer(c.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        List<Product> pList = c.list();
        String size = "<option>Select size</option>";
        for (Product p : pList) {
            size += "<option>"+p.getProductSize()+"</option>";
        }
        resp.getWriter().write(size);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to remove all duplicated sizes form the product but this wont work for me any suggustions

Answer (score 0):

Change line

`c.setResultTransformer(c.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

with

`c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add( 
                   Projections.distinct(Projections.property("productSize")
                ));
```